# how many days between two dates

Tags: java, calendar, date-format

I am basically trying to calculate count days between two dates but when parsing the date to calendar, i can not specify the wrong date format.For example if i do this,  it automatically converts the date to 01/02/2017.please help

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");    
Calendar cal1 = new GregorianCalendar();    
try {
    Date date=df.parse("32/01/2017");
    cal1.setTime(date);
} 
catch (ParseException e) 
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please enter a valid date");
}
```

Comment: I would suggest looking through the `java.time` package for something that can do this.

Comment: What is the question? That trying to parse the 32nd of January becomes the 1st of February, and you wouldn't want that?

Answer (score 1):

> ***i can not specify the wrong date format***

**Yes we can**, set lenient in the date format and the parsing will validate the string, throwing an exception if you try to parse a invalid date like **"32/01/2017"**